# query in android

Tags: android, sqlite

the app crash if enable `text =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_BODY));`

```
public String getPhone(long rowId){
        SQLiteDatabase cb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String text = null ;
        Cursor cursor=cb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY,KEY_EMAIL},KEY_ROWID + " = ?"+rowId, null, null, null,null);

    //text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_BODY));


                return text;

}
```

Comment: -1. Please at least try to write up a decent question next time. Including an error log and more information what you want to do and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your not passing the parameter right:

1. You must provide string args to filter query, thus pass String param to your method
2. I assume you are passing current indexes and constants.

Heres how you do it:

```
public String getPhone(String rowId){ 
    SQLiteDatabase cb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
    String text = null ; 
    Cursor cursor=cb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] 
        {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY,KEY_EMAIL},KEY_ROWID + " = ?",new String[]{rowId}, null, null,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        text =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_BODY));
    else
        return "";
```